# Fixed height and width for JTextField

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I've been working with Java Swing recently and when I try to add 3 JTextFields beneath each other they fill out the whole JFrame. But I want them to have a fixed height and width. What can I do?

Since I'm new to this topic I wasn't able to try out many things. I haven't found anything in other forums either.

My goal was to make a simple GUI for Users to fill in their credentials. Those credentials should be filled into an array but I haven't got there yet.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PeopleGUI extends JFrame{
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    JTextField jt = new JTextField(30);
    JTextField jt1 = new JTextField(30);
    JTextField jt2 = new JTextField(30);
    JButton jb = new JButton("Enter");

    public PeopleGUI(){
        setTitle("PeopleGUI");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        jp.add(jt);
        jp.add(jt1);
        jp.add(jt2);

        jt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String input = jt.getText();
                jl.setText(input);
            }
        });

        jp.add(jb);

        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String input = jt.getText();
                jl.setText(input);
            }
        });

        jp.add(jl);
        add(jp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PeopleGUI p = new PeopleGUI();
    }
}
```

I expect JTextFields that don't adjust to the size of the window.

Currently, it is looking like this:
  [image: Current look].

But it should rather look like:
  [image: Expected look].

Comment: Other tips: `setVisible(true); setSize(400,200);` 1) Don't set a size, that's no better than a guess. Add all the components, then `pack()` the top level container. It will be the smallest it can be, while still assigning enough space for whatever it contains. 2) Always make the `setVisible(..)` call last, usually just after `pack()` is called. This will avoid artifacts in layout, or the size changing after the GUI appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Layout e.g. BoxLayout. You will find some documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Not sure why this answer was accepted. The posted code DOES  use a BoxLayout. The problem is that that a BoxLayout allows components to grow to their maximum size. The button does not grow since its maximum size is equal to its preferred size. The text fields grow because they have a greater maximum size. One solution is to wrap that panel into a panel using a FlowLayout. Then add the wrapped panel to the frame. Or you can use other layouts like a `GridBagLayout`. In this case the tutorial link is helpful fore more information.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

That layout is easily reproduced by putting 3 panels, each with a centered `FlowLayout`, into a single column `GridLayout`.

**The *important* part is the `FlowLayout`, which will respect the preferred size of the components it is displaying.**

[Combinations of different layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) are often used when making a GUI. The idea is for each to handle a small part of the layout needs of the entire user interface. Here is a screenshot from that answer which lists the layouts used, by way of titled borders for each one.

[image]

But I think it would be better if the RHS of the label and the LHS of the fields are aligned vertically. To do that, use a single `GridBagLayout`.